# squeeze with lvm on top of raid 0 fails to boot using grub2

Tags: debian, raid, lvm, debian-squeeze, grub2

```
GRUB Loading
Welcome to GRUB!

error: no such device: <GUID>.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0), (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> set
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/grub
root=hd0,msdos1
grub rescue> ls /boot
error: file not found.
grub rescue> insmod linux
error: file not found.
grub rescue> insmod normal
error: file not found.
grub rescue> normal
Unkown command 'normal'
grub rescue> boot
Unkown command 'boot'
```

I've tried using a Debian Live CD in rescue mode but it can not mount any partition.

**Questions:**

1. How can I recover from this and eventually boot into the system without losing the data?
2. Can I make a backup without booting at all and recover the data from it later?

Comment: If you boot into a livecd, install mdadm and scan your partitions, can you see the array?

Comment: I can only wish I could. Its a little late since the server has been re-purposed. Luckily it was a test server and not a production server. Still its a good idea to try this option in case the lighting strikes the same place twice.

Comment: What were the circumstances leading up to this - a clean install, or a crash of some sort?

Comment: A power outage which reset the BIOS settings to default for some arbitrary reason. The default settings had the RAID controller disabled. I've only realized this last fact after several failed attempts to restore GRUB2. By then it was passed the point of no return. The initial message did not contain the `error: no such device: <GUID>.` line.